# How to properly create a trigger in workbench?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create a simple triger functionality in my DB, so I can change a value in one of my tables when the other one is updated.

I have an oversimplified library database and the tables in question are `boakloan` and `bookcopy`. 
In `bookloan` I have a foreign key to `bookcopy`, where I have an `isAvailable` column. The defaul value of this column is 1(true), and having a new entry in my `bookloan` table would mean that a copy of a book is borrowed, and it's no longer available, so I want to change the value of `isAvailable` to 0(false) for this record.

I tried to write a trigger for that in a couple of ways, but nothing worked.

Here is my last code :

```
    USE `libdb`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS libdb.bookcopy_update$$
USE `libdb`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `libdb`.`bookcopy_update`
BEFORE INSERT 
ON `bookloan` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN 

UPDATE bookcopy 
SET bookcopy.isAvailable = 0
WHERE bookcopy.isAvailable = 1 
AND bookcopy.idBookCopy = bookloan.BookCopy_idBookCopyFK;


END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Can someone help make this work?

With the current version I get the following error : `ERROR 1054: 1054: Unknown column 'bookloan.BookCopy_idBookCopyFK' in 'where clause'`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, I changed this part in my code before posting here, but it still won't work. I will edit the question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get that error because in this query (from your trigger body):

```
UPDATE bookcopy 
SET bookcopy.isAvailable = 0
WHERE bookcopy.isAvailable = 1 
AND bookcopy.idBookCopy = bookloan.BookCopy_idBookCopyFK;
```

there's no `bookloan` defined.

Replace `bookloan.BookCopy_idBookCopyFK` with `NEW.BookCopy_idBookCopyFK`.

Comment: Thanks, this made it work :) The funny part is that i had this code in an earlier version, but other things were wrong. Obviously i have no idea what i am doing